# pyspark: removing mirosecond from timestamp

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am working on a pyspark script and one of the required transformation is to convert the microsecond timestamp into seconds timestamp -

1. Read the parquet file as input
2. Determine if any column is "timestamp".(Will be in microseconds)

   ```
   Example - 2019-03-30 19:56:14.520138
   ```
3. If yes, convert it to 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' format

   ```
   After conversion - 2019-03-30 19:56:14
   ```
4. Write the dataframe in parquet format back to s3.

I have tried, the below but it doesn't work. The returned dataframe still shows microsecond.

```
df = spark.read.parquet(p_input_loc)

def customize_df(df):
    getTimestampCol = list(
                filter(lambda x: "timestamp" in x, df.dtypes))
    print(getTimestampCol)
    """[('created_at', 'timestamp'), ('updated_at', 'timestamp')]"""
    if getTimestampCol:
        for row in getTimestampCol:
            df = df.withColumn(row[0], f.to_timestamp(row[0], 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'))
        return df
    else:
        return df
```

So I need help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here problem is with your function usage.
The to_timestamp function parse the date in the formatit is provided and then convert it to timestamp but to change the format you need to use date_format function.

Here is an example

```
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([("2020-01-01 11:22:59.9989","12312020","31122020"), ("2020-01-01 11:22:59.9989","12312020","31122020" )], ["ID","Start_date","End_date"])

df2.withColumn('ss',f.date_format(df2.ID.cast(t.TimestampType()),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')).select('ss','ID').show(2, False)

+-------------------+------------------------+
|ss                 |ID                      |
+-------------------+------------------------+
|2020-01-01 11:22:59|2020-01-01 11:22:59.9989|
|2020-01-01 11:22:59|2020-01-01 11:22:59.9989|
+-------------------+------------------------+
```

So change your

```
df = df.withColumn(row[0], f.to_timestamp(row[0], 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'))
```

with

```
df = df.withColumn(row[0], f.date_format(row[0], 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
```

as your column is already of timestampType.

Hope it helps